# ReactDOM.render() vs export default class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using rc-time-picker and when I do it like this

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import TimePicker from 'rc-time-picker';
import './Offers.css';
export default class OffersPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <TimePicker></TimePicker>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

it freezes the entire website after I select a time without any console error message, but the examples in the documentation always do it like this

```
import 'rc-time-picker/assets/index.css';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import moment from 'moment';
import TimePicker from 'rc-time-picker';

ReactDom.render(
  <TimePicker defaultValue={moment()} showSecond={false} minuteStep={15} />
, document.getElementById('__react-content'));
```

Is there a difference between using export default class versus ReactDom.render?

Comment: Have you tried just like that: `<TimePicker />` instead of `<TimePicker></TimePicker>`?

Comment: Hmm, it seems this is not the problem since it works as it is. I've tried it on codesandbox.io. So, the problem must be somewhere else but your code is so plain.

Comment: well I'm also using webpack and babel. Maybe that's why?

Comment: Not particularly, most of the apps use Webpack and Babel. codesandbox.io uses create-react-app and it uses those, too. Maybe I can try it in the local in a while.

Comment: Well, it works on the local, too with create-react-app.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it work like that:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "rc-time-picker/assets/index.css";
import TimePicker from "rc-time-picker";

export default class OffersPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return <TimePicker />;
  }
}
```

test here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/8ykz96qkr0

Try also other browsers.